# Pi Zero Segmentation Faults

Tags: pi-zero

I have two raspberry pi zeros.I wrote program using nodejs and opencv4nodejs. It works as intended on the first raspberry pi zero. On the second pi zero it crashes frequently due to Segmentation Fault. The weird thing is; If I switch the sd cards, device 1 stills works as intended and device 2 still crashes from Segmentation Fault. This confirms that the software builds are correct and leads me to believe that the second raspberry Pi is different hardware? Shouldn't all raspberry pi zero's be the same? Why would one PI zero get segmentation fault and another works fine? Is there away I can look at specs of the physical hardware to compare is there is a difference?

Also, tried a thrid raspberry pi zero. It errored with Segmentation fault after running for a few mins. I tried with Raspberry Pi B+, no segmentation faults. Again the 1st raspberry pi zero runs without SegFault. It shouldnt be a ram issue right? unless the other Pi Zero ram is messed up.

Comment: I used npm segfault-handler to try and debug. I got message back "lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6(__default_rt_sa_restorer+0) [0xb6c08130]

Comment: it could be that the first Pi Zero is failing in some way and allows your program to execute without an error

Comment: Thats a interesting thought. Not a clue on what that might be. Didn't expect that the first pi zero could be faulty.  Is there a way to run diagnostics on? this would be a hardware issue right?

Comment: no idea how to debug ...  i only said that the working one could be faulty because i have seen that happen with computer equipment

Comment: great. Vaulable information for me. Im going to upgrade from pi zero for now. The app preform amazing well on PI B. Ill come back to this obstacle when Im older. The zero is defeating. Unless anyone has other raspberry pi zero configuration to suggest :) -thanks

Comment: try reducing the code ... find the smallest number of command lines that exhibit the failure ... maybe post the code here if you can

Comment: Is there any hardware attached to the RasPi?

Comment: just RasPI camera module